# Gradle tests runs twice

Tags: java, junit, gradle

I wrote network tests that require before running start network server. I do not want after every task run/stop server so i grouped them with suite.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    TestStatus.class,
    TestLogin.class,
    TestGame.class,
})
```

All works fine untill i run tests in gradle. Gradle runs first tests seperate and because it's based on working server they fails. After that it's rune suite that passes. How i can fix this?

Comment: did you find any solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
test {
    include "com/foo/MySuite.class"
    include ...
}
```

For API details, see the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Comment: Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [ru.ensemplix.server.network.TestNetwork]

Comment: Looks like suites can only be included using the older `include` API. I've updated my answer accordingly.